# Django executing shell script from views and not to wait until the executed script finishes

Tags: django

Currently I am working on a django project where I would like to kick off a python shell script to execute some tasks from one of my views in the Django application.

What I am trying to achive is from my Django application when I call a view function it executes the shell script but not to wait until the shell script finishes. So the Django app finishes with the request but in the background the kicked off process is still progressing. So the Django app while the kicked off process is runing is able to receive new requests.

Is there any way to do this or any better way to kick of separate processes from Django and monitor the status of them?

What I tried:

def example_view(request):
os.system("my shell script")
"Code does not step to the next instruction while os.system is running"

Comment: Have you tried django-celery?

Answer (score 0):

With what you have mentioned in your question and assuming you are using Django 3.1 or +

As per my understanding what you want to do is set up an asynchronous view.
An Async view will allow your application to run certain code(in your case a shell script) inside the view which will not hinder its usual flow.
Repeating the exact technical detail will create redundancy and vagueness in this answer so I would suggest you to refer the [offical documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/async/) on how to do so.

Comment: async def test_socket(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        print("TEST CONNECTION")
        os.system("my script'")
        print(os.getpid())
        print("Process kicked off")
        return JsonResponse(list({}), safe=False)

and i received the below error

AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: I hope you really WANT to execute SHELL SCRIPT inside your django application. I did not mentioned it in my answer because it could go out of the topic, but executing commands can poise a security risk to your application and your server which might cost you a hefty $ to recover from. If you know what you are doing and your situation does call to implement scripts then proceed with your approach.

Comment: as fas as your 
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'get' goes you need to refer the doc which I have linked in the answer, what you are trying to do is implement a function based view and calling it with a class based url syntax. I would suggest you go through the doc in that way it will solve you a lot of time scavanging for code.